# NoSuchElement Exception in Thread in TextFile Program

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist, text-files

[image: error]

Hi. I'm having the issue in an error of exception. I don't know what is wrong. But please help me fix this. I'm trying to store data from the file to ArrayList and display the data in the ArrayList. Here, I attached my code and data [Code and data source](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oB5e370_VOFX6ymPjApG9QR6KCTIN7KW?usp=sharing).

Comment: What does the `NoSuchElementException` mean?  Have you looked at the `nextToken()` method signature?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextToken()

Answer (score 0):

the NoSuchElementException appears because you are calling `input.nextToken();` while input doesn't have any token.It's due to the last empty line of your file listbook.txt. By deleting this line, the exception shouldn't appear.

A proper manner could be to ensure that you have sufficient tokens to retrieve all your fields for a given line.

```
    public class TextFile 
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            try 
            {
            FileReader read = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ogawi\\Downloads\\listbook.txt");
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(read);
            Book B = new Book();
            ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
            String data = null;
            StringTokenizer input = null;
            
            while((data = bf.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                input = new StringTokenizer(data,";");
                //we ensure that we have enough tokens to retrieve all fields
                if(input.countTokens() == 6)
                {
                    String title = input.nextToken();
                    String author = input.nextToken();
                    String publisher = input.nextToken();
                    String genre = input.nextToken();
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(input.nextToken());
                    int page = Integer.parseInt(input.nextToken());
                        
                    B = new Book(title, author, publisher, genre, year, page);
                    bookList.add(B);
                }
               
                
                
            }
            
            //This part of code has been moved outside the while loop
            //to avoid to print the total content of the array each time
            //an element is added
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0;i<bookList.size();i++)
            {
                B = (Book)bookList.get(i);
                System.out.println(B.toString());
                System.out.println("=============================");
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("Number of Books: " + count);
            bf.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
        { System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());}
        
        catch(EOFException eof)
        { System.out.println(eof.getMessage());}
        
        catch(IOException io)
        { System.out.println(io.getMessage());}
        
        finally
        { System.out.println("System end here..TQ!!");}
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are helping.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the extra line without book information:
[image]

You can see the line 31 and 32 in above figure.

To solve this issue you can add one if condition **data.contains(";")** . Text file has **;** delimiter if we check the condition if given line has **;** delimiter then it won't cause an issue.

```
        while ((data = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            if (data.contains(";")) {
                input = new StringTokenizer(data, ";");
                String title = input.nextToken();
                String author = input.nextToken();
                String publisher = input.nextToken();
                String genre = input.nextToken();
                int year = Integer.parseInt(input.nextToken());
                int page = Integer.parseInt(input.nextToken());

                B = new Book(title, author, publisher, genre, year, page);
                bookList.add(B);

                int count = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < bookList.size(); i++) {
                    B = (Book) bookList.get(i);
                    System.out.println(B.toString());
                    System.out.println("=============================");
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Number of Books: " + count);
            }
        }
```

Here is the screenshot for successful execution of the code.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It helps. Tq